# Learning reactJs Flux and encounter the addEventListener confusion

Tags: reactjs, flux

I am learn reactjs flux pattern from the link below

https://scotch.io/tutorials/getting-to-know-flux-the-react-js-architecture

I get completely confused and lost with this following bit, when will the following code ever been trigger or used? i do not see any where in the app where the this._onChange will be trigger... please help and explain any suggestion is appreciated as i  am start to learn.

```
// Listen for changes
  componentDidMount: function() {
    ShoeStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },

  // Unbind change listener
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    ShoesStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
  },
```

in the store, does it means in order to trigger the update need to run **ShoesStore.emitChange()**?

```
// Emit Change event
  emitChange: function() {
    this.emit('change');
  },

  // Add change listener
  addChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.on('change', callback);
  },

  // Remove change listener
  removeChangeListener: function(callback) {
    this.removeListener('change', callback);
  }
```

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-nodes-event-module--net-35941 is a good high-level overview of this pattern.

Comment: @BinaryMuse thanks mate i do understand EventEmitter, but i am just confused about when is been triggered? As dytori state the store will auto invokes onChange.

Comment: When you're creating a store you'll usually call `emitChange()` yourself (it's not usually automatic).

Comment: @BinaryMuse thanks mate i will test it out. Just realise it's the master again... Brandon.

Comment: @BinaryMuse you are right, find out this line of code

  // If action was responded to, emit change event
  ProductStore.emitChange();

Answer (score 0):

In typical `Flux` app, your store emit change (as `EventEmitter`) and `_onChange` is invoked because it has been assigned by `addChangeListner`, which needs to be removed afterwards otherwise it cause memory leak. `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` is invoked at certain life cycle phases, as method names say, just after the component is mounted, and just before unmounted.

Comment: so this *_this.onchange* eventlistener is been added, but when is going to be trigger? thanks (trigger automatically ?)

Comment: When store emits change. It kicks the assigned event listeners.

Comment: And yes, emitting change automatically invokes `onChange`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer: (summary from BinaryMuse)

When you're creating a store you'll usually call emitChange() yourself (it's not usually automatic).